# Cannot launch nao_driver

Tags: ros, nao-driver, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Go to Edit2 for the current error]

Hello, I am trying to launch nao_driver with the command:

```
NAO_IP=10.51.81.15 roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver.launch
```

or

```
NAO_IP=10.51.81.15 FORCE_PYTHON=true roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver.launch
```

but i get the following errors.

```
MyName@Wael:~$ NAO_IP=10.51.81.15 roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver.launch
... logging to /home/MyName/.ros/log/79d95dc2-8379-11e3-8cbe-90b11c6e6bd9/roslaunch-Wael-19571.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server Wael:38416/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    nao_behaviors (nao_driver/nao_behaviors.py)
    nao_controller (nao_driver/nao_controller.py)
    nao_leds (nao_driver/nao_leds.py)
    nao_sensors (nao_driver/nao_sensors_cpp)
    nao_speech (nao_driver/nao_speech.py)
    nao_tactile (nao_driver/nao_tactile.py)
    nao_walker (nao_driver/nao_walker.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [19585]
ROS_MASTER_URI=localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 79d95dc2-8379-11e3-8cbe-90b11c6e6bd9
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [19598]
started core service [/rosout]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nao_driver/nao_sensors_cpp]: cant locate node [nao_sensors_cpp] in package [nao_driver]
process[nao_walker-3]: started with pid [19610]
process[nao_controller-4]: started with pid [19611]
process[nao_behaviors-5]: started with pid [19612]
process[nao_leds-6]: started with pid [19615]
process[nao_speech-7]: started with pid [19618]
process[nao_tactile-8]: started with pid [19623]
failed to load symbols, rosdep will not function properly
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/rosout/rosout: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros6HeaderC1Ev
[WARN] [WallTime: 1390404352.268687] Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. 0 bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details.
[rosout-1] process has died [pid 19598, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/rosout/rosout __name:=rosout __log:=/home/MyName/.ros/log/79d95dc2-8379-11e3-8cbe-90b11c6e6bd9/rosout-1.log].
log file: /home/MyName/.ros/log/79d95dc2-8379-11e3-8cbe-90b11c6e6bd9/rosout-1*.log
respawning...
[rosout-1] restarting process
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [19751]
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/rosout/rosout: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros6HeaderC1Ev
[WARN] [WallTime: 1390404352.577597] Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. 0 bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details.
[rosout-1] process has died [pid 19751, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/rosout/rosout __name:=rosout __log:=/home/MyName/.ros/log/79d95dc2-8379-11e3-8cbe-90b11c6e6bd9/rosout-1.log].
log file: /home/MyName/.ros/log/79d95dc2-8379-11e3-8cbe-90b11c6e6bd9/rosout-1*.log
respawning...
[rosout-1] restarting process
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Thank you AHornung, that seems to help a little. The errors has changed, but are still similar to what they were.

```
setting /run_id to f2362376-837f-11e3-b5cf-90b11c6e6bd9
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [20614]
started core service [/rosout]/
process[nao_sensors-2]: started with pid [20626]
process[nao_walker-3]: started with pid [20627]
process[nao_controller-4]: started with pid [20628]
process[nao_behaviors-5]: started with pid [20629]
process[nao_leds-6]: started with pid [20634]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_sensors.py", line 44, in <module>
    from tf import transformations
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _tf import *
ImportError: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros6HeaderD1Ev
process[nao_speech-7]: started with pid [20639]
process[nao_tactile-8]: started with pid [20646]
================================================================================REQUIRED process [nao_sensors-2] has died!
process has died [pid 20626, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_sensors.py --pip=10.51.81.15 --pport=9559 __name:=nao_sensors __log:=/home/antoinerioux/.ros/log/f2362376-837f-11e3-b5cf-90b11c6e6bd9/nao_sensors-2.log].
log file: /home/antoinerioux/.ros/log/f2362376-837f-11e3-b5cf-90b11c6e6bd9/nao_sensors-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[nao_tactile-8] killing on exit
[nao_speech-7] killing on exit
[nao_leds-6] killing on exit
[nao_behaviors-5] killing on exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_tactile.py", line 35, in <module>
    import rospy
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 67, in <module>
    [nao_controller-4] killing on exit
from roscpp.srv import GetLoggers, GetLoggersResponse, SetLoggerLevel, SetLoggerLevelResponse
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roscpp/srv/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._GetLoggers import *
[nao_walker-3] killing on exit
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roscpp/srv/_GetLoggers.py", line 92, in <module>
    import roscpp.msg
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roscpp/msg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._Logger import *
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roscpp/msg/_Logger.py", line 1, in <module>
    """autogenerated by genpy from roscpp/Logger.msg. Do not edit."""
KeyboardInterrupt
[nao_sensors-2] killing on exit
failed to load symbols, rosdep will not function properly
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_leds.py", line 173, in <module>
    node = NaoLeds()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_leds.py", line 58, in __init__
    rospy.init_node( self.NODE_NAME )
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 317, in init_node
    raise rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException("init_node interrupted before it could complete")
rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException: init_node interrupted before it could complete
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_behaviors.py", line 139, in <module>
    node = NaoBehaviors()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_behaviors.py", line 59, in __init__
    rospy.init_node( self.NODE_NAME )
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 317, in init_node
    raise rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException("init_node interrupted before it could complete")
rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException: init_node interrupted before it could complete
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/rosout/rosout: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros6HeaderC1Ev
[WARN] [WallTime: 1390407131.509740] Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. 0 bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details.
[nao_speech-7] escalating to SIGTERM
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Edit2:
I resolved the problem above with the suggestion on another question at:
answers.ros.org/question/120541/problem-of-running-rosrun-turtlesim-turtlesim_node/

But now I have yet another error!

```
    antoinerioux@Wael:~$ roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver.launch force_python:=true nao_ip:=10.51.81.15
... logging to /home/antoinerioux/.ros/log/e05386e2-8449-11e3-8e29-90b11c6e6bd9/roslaunch-Wael-16790.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server Wael:59162/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    nao_behaviors (nao_driver/nao_behaviors.py)
    nao_controller (nao_driver/nao_controller.py)
    nao_leds (nao_driver/nao_leds.py)
    nao_sensors (nao_driver/nao_sensors.py)
    nao_speech (nao_driver/nao_speech.py)
    nao_tactile (nao_driver/nao_tactile.py)
    nao_walker (nao_driver/nao_walker.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [16804]
ROS_MASTER_URI=//localhost:11311

setting /run_id to e05386e2-8449-11e3-8e29-90b11c6e6bd9
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [16817]
started core service [/rosout]/
process[nao_sensors-2]: started with pid [16829]
process[nao_walker-3]: started with pid [16830]
process[nao_controller-4]: started with pid [16831]
process[nao_behaviors-5]: started with pid [16832]
process[nao_leds-6]: started with pid [16837]
process[nao_speech-7]: started with pid [16840]
process[nao_tactile-8]: started with pid [16841]
failed to load symbols, rosdep will not function properly
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_sensors.py", line 44, in <module>
    from tf import transformations
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from listener import TransformListener, TransformerROS
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/listener.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tf import transformations
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/transformations.py", line 174, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: No module named multiarray
failed to load symbols, rosdep will not function properly
================================================================================REQUIRED process [nao_sensors-2] has died!
process has died [pid 16829, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_sensors.py --pip=10.51.81.15 --pport=9559 __name:=nao_sensors __log:=/home/antoinerioux/.ros/log/e05386e2-8449-11e3-8e29-90b11c6e6bd9/nao_sensors-2.log].
log file: /home/antoinerioux/.ros/log/e05386e2-8449-11e3-8e29-90b11c6e6bd9/nao_sensors-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[nao_tactile-8] killing on exit
[nao_speech-7] killing on exit
[nao_leds-6] killing on exit
[nao_behaviors-5] killing on exit
[nao_controller-4] killing on exit
[nao_walker-3] killing on exit
[nao_sensors-2] killing on exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_tactile.py", line 192, in <module>
    ROSNaoTactileModule = NaoTactile("ROSNaoTactileModule")
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_tactile.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.init_almodule()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_tactile.py", line 121, in init_almodule
    self.broker = ALBroker("%sBroker" % self.moduleName, self.ip, self.port, self.pip, self.pport)
  File "/home/antoinerioux/pynaoqi-python-2.7-naoqi-1.14-linux64/inaoqi.py", line 164, in __init__
    this = _inaoqi.new_broker(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
Exception TypeError: "in method 'module_getName', argument 1 of type 'AL::module *'" in <bound method NaoTactile.__del__ of <__main__.NaoTactile;  >> ignored
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Reinstalled Ubuntu and ROS. Everything worked on the first try after that when using the syntax proposed in the answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120806/cannot-launch-nao_driver/) by [TopSecret](https://answers.ros.org/users/11111/topsecret/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to run `roslaunch nao_driver.launch force_python:=true`

(with the optional `NAO_IP` in front). NAO_IP is an environment variable that you can globally set or directly set before launching, whereas `force_python` is a launch file argument (you can also set nao_ip=... as a launch file argument as alternative but vice-versa there is no environment variable called `FORCE_PYTHON` used).

That import error looks like a general problem with ROS:

```
ImportError: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros6HeaderD1Ev
```

Are other nodes in ROS (specifically Python nodes) working fine, did you manually change things in /opt/ros/hydro/...?

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TopSecret](https://answers.ros.org/users/11111/topsecret/) on 2014-01-22**:
Since I just started with ROS + Nao + Ubuntu, I wouldn't really know what other nodes to try for verification. I am mostly following tutorials at the moment. I don't remember changing anything in this directory.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-01-22**:
On what operating system is that happening? Did you freshly install ROS from the repositories?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-01-22**:
Also, did you source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash

**Comment by [TopSecret](https://answers.ros.org/users/11111/topsecret/) on 2014-01-22**:
I solved the symbol problem following this answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/120541/problem-of-running-rosrun-turtlesim-turtlesim_node/.